# Porque puedo acceder a una URL pero no me responde si le hago PIN

Tags: http, tcp

Tengo una pregunta puntual, ¿porque puedo acceder a una URL pero no puedo hacerle ping?, la ip es 190.90.250.238.

Answer (score 6):

En TCP/IP existen diferentes protocolos que funcionan a diferente nivel. En el caso de un url, generalmente se publican utilizando el protocolo http (un protocolo de nivel aplicación que funciona sobre TCP). Ping utiliza un protocolo distinto llamado ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol). Algunos servidores o firewalls bloquean este protocolo por seguridad. Probablemente ese sea tu caso, algún Firewall o configuración del servidor está bloqueando / deshabilitando el protocolo ICMP.